# Error al instalar pip install sklearn / pip install scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Al instalar pip install sklearn o pip install scikit-learn a traves de cmd me sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\KEVVELAS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\KEVVELAS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8rc0qj21\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
          cwd: C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\
Complete output (37 lines):
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 290, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 286, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
    config = configuration()
  File "C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 174, in configuration
    config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
    config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 999, in get_subpackage
    config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
    config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
  File "sklearn\setup.py", line 76, in configuration
    maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
  File "C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 42, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
    with_openmp = check_openmp_support()
  File "C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\sklearn\_build_utils\openmp_helpers.py", line 83, in check_openmp_support
    ccompiler.compile(['test_openmp.c'], output_dir='objects',
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
    vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
    return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1075, in __init__
    self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 547, in __init__
    vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vs_ver())
  File "c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 561, in _find_latest_available_vs_ver
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
```

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   'c:\users\kevvelas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe'
>   -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1e5i5bj9\scikit-learn\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record
>   'C:\Users\KEVVELAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8rc0qj21\install-record.txt'
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Intente instalando los siguientes paquetes según lo que investigue en otras paginas y me sigue saliendo el mismo error:

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U wheel
pip3 install scikit-learn
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al fin pude solucionarlo
Para los que les sale este mismo problema yo hice lo siguiente
Desintale la version actual de python(3.8) e instale la version 3.7.0 y ya se pudo instalar :)

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, sólo tienes que leer la documentación actual de Python 3 y verás que muchas de las librerias aún no funcionan correctamente sobre las versiones superiores a Python 3.8

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La respuesta parece más bien un comentario. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].